# Problem with installing phpMyAdmin

Tags: apache2, mysql, php, phpmyadmin

I am trying to install phpMyAdmin:

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

and I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Any advice would be much appreciated

Comment: If I were in your shoes I would install phpmyadmin inside a docker.

Answer (score 0):

This error code means that `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` does not exists
you probably did not install MySQL server or it is not running.

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
```

Comment: I believe that the MySQL server is installed - `sudo mysql` outputs `Welcome to the MySQL monitor. ` and I can execute sql commands from the command-line, lie `show databases`.